# Recent progress on the next-to-shortest-path problem for directed graphs?

Tags: np-hardness, shortest-path

In the paper "Computing strictly-second shortest paths" (1997), Lalgudi and Papaefthymiou consider the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a directed graph with edge-weighting $w$. Let $u,v$ be vertices in $V(G)$. Let $p_1$ be a path of minimum weight from $u$ to $v$. Compute a *simple* path $p_2$ from $u$ to $v$ with $w(p_2) > w(p_1)$ and such that for any other path $p$ from $u$ to $v$ with $w(p) > w(p_1)$, we have $w(p) \ge w(p_2)$.

They prove that this problem is NP-hard. Their proof involves choosing a weight function that takes value $1$ on a certain edge and $0$ elsewhere, so it relies in a fundamental way on the possibility of there being edges of weight $0$.

Is anything known about whether the problem remains NP-hard when restricted to unweighted digraphs, that is directed graphs for which $w(e) = 1$ for each $e \in E(G)$?

---

*EDIT:
The variant in undirected graphs,
and the variant where the goal is to find a (not-necessarily simple) *walk* (as opposed to a path),
are known to be in P.  Here's a summary:*

| graph type | edge weights | path or walk? | result | paper |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| directed | non-negative | path | NP-hard | [1997] |
| either | non-negative | **walk** | in P | [1997] |
| **DAG** | non-negative | path = walk | in P | [1997] |
| **undirected** | non-negative | path | in P | [2004, 2006, 2011, 2012a,b] |
| directed | **strictly positive** | path | open | [2011,2015] |

(Note that there is also a separate body of work on fast algorithms for finding $k\ge 2$ shortest paths, e.g. [1998], where distinct path lengths are not required.)

---

- [1997] *Lalgudi, Kumar N.; Papaefthymiou, Marios C.*, [**Computing
  strictly-second shortest
  paths**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(97)00122-1), Inf.
  Process. Lett. 63, No. 4, 177-181 (1997).
  [ZBL1336.68137](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1336.68137).
- [2004] *Krasikov, I.;
  Noble, S. D.*, [**Finding next-to-shortest paths in a
  graph**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2004.06.020), Inf. Process.
  Lett. 92, No. 3, 117-119 (2004).
  [ZBL1173.68609](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1173.68609).
- [2006] *Li, Shisheng; Sun, Guangzhong; Chen, Guoliang*,
  [**Improved algorithm for finding next-to-shortest
  paths**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2006.04.013), Inf. Process.
  Lett. 99, No. 5, 192-194 (2006).
  [ZBL1185.68489](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1185.68489).
- [2011] *Kao, Kuo-Hua; Chang, Jou-Ming; Wang, Yue-Li;
  Juan, Justie Su-Tzu*, [**A quadratic algorithm for finding
  next-to-shortest paths in
  graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00453-010-9402-4), Algorithmica
  61, No. 2, 402-418 (2011).
  [ZBL1250.05108](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1250.05108).
- [2012a] *Cong Zhang; Hiroshi Nagamochi*, [**The
  next-to-shortest path in undirected graphs with nonnegative
  weights**](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.5555/2523693.2523695). In
  Proceedings of the Eighteenth Computing: The Australasian Theory
  Symposium - Volume 128 (CATS '12). Australian Computer Society, Inc.,
  AUS, 13–20.
- [2012b] *B.Y. Wu, J.-L. Guo, and Y.-L. Wang*, [**A linear time
  algorithm for the next-to-shortest path problem on undirected graphs
  with nonnegative edge
  lengths**](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1203.5235), 2012,
  arXiv:1203.5235 [cs.DS].
- [2015] *Wu, Bang Ye;
  Wang, Hung-Lung*, [**The next-to-shortest path problem on directed
  graphs with positive edge
  weights**](https://doi.org/10.1002/net.21598), Networks 65, No. 3,
  205-211 (2015). [ZBL1386.05082](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1386.05082),
  (pdf
  [here](http://cedric.cnam.fr/%7Ebentzc/INITREC/Files/CP11.pdf)).
- [1998] *Eppstein, David*, [**Finding
  the k shortest paths**](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539795290477),
  SIAM J. Comput. 28, No. 2, 652-673 (1998).
  [ZBL0912.05057](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0912.05057).

Comment: We call those unweighted graphs

Comment: This paper solves the unweighted problem in $O(n^2)$: [A Quadratic Algorithm for Finding Next-to-Shortest
Paths in Graphs](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00453-010-9402-4)

Comment: In the Conclusion section of paper referred in the comment of  isaacg the authors say: "the time-complexity of the next-to-shortest path problem in digraphs when the edge lengths are required to be strictly positive is still open."

Comment: The confusion here is that the $O(n^2)$-time algorithm is for *undirected* graphs  (with positive edge weights).  Later work gives poly-time algorithm for undirected graphs with non-negative edges weights.  But as far as I can tell (as of 2023) the variant on *directed* graphs with *positive* edge weights (asking for a *simple* path, not a walk), is open.  [I attempted to address all this in an edit of the post.]

Comment: By the way, as of 2023, the following similar problem is still open: given an unweighted directed graph G and vertices s and t, decide if there is a a simple path from s to t which is strictly longer than the shortest path. (It needn't be the next-to-shortest, just longer than the shortest.) This is explicitly stated here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.01781 "it remains open whether k-Longest Detour is in P even for the special case of k = 1"